# How does a DotNetCore Console App reference an executable in the solution?

Tags: .net

I'm really new to the new .NET Core Framework and struggling with how libraries and executables are handled now. I have a solution with two projects, the main console app, and an exe project. I'm trying to launch the exe from my main Console app. In the past, all projects in a solution were built to a bin directory.

Now that .NET Core does a lot of work in memory, there's no executable unless you build with the new tooling, DNX/DotNet. On the properties page there is an option to output on build, but this creates a dll with a batch file to launch it.

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to build an exe at build time like we used to be able to do so I can test like it will be in production, with built exes and not dlls.

Comment: I believe that .net core doesnt create exe's because it is now platform agnostic and you wouldnt be able to run that exe on linux or osx. As I understand it your main console app should call "dotnet run <DLL here>'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dotnet-publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-publish%20dotnet-publish), you can find an example [here](http://druss.co/2016/08/deploy-and-run-net-core-application-without-installed-runtime-self-contained-applications/)

You'll need to select your target platform. The solution is still kind of workaround, but it gives you an exe entry point.

The final goal of the .NET team is to give plain support for such scenario, with optional possibility to pack everything in a single executable (source: [Asp.net community standup](http://druss.co/2016/08/deploy-and-run-net-core-application-without-installed-runtime-self-contained-applications/), but I don't remember which episode(s)).